# Messages are disappearing after refreshing the page from topic

Tags: apache-kafka

When we use retention.ms = 604800000 messages are getting vanish.

We only have one consumer, which is a kafka connector and before it reads data from the topic, messages start disappearing.

```
{
  "topic_name": "test",
  "partitions_count": 6,
  "replication_factor": 3,
  "configs": [
    {
      "name": "cleanup.policy",
      "value": "delete"
    },
    {
      "name": "compression.type",
      "value": "producer"
    },
    {
      "name": "confluent.key.schema.validation",
      "value": "false"
    },
    {
      "name": "confluent.value.schema.validation",
      "value": "false"
    },
    {
      "name":"retention.ms",
      "value":"-1"
    }
  ]
}
```

Note: When i use retention.ms=-1, messages are not getting disappered.

1.why messages re getting vanish?
2.is it good way to use retention.ms = -1(infinite)? if i use -1 when these messages will gets deleted?

Answer (score 1):

Messages are disappearing as a result of the timestamp I'm using in message produce API. We should use latest timestamp to avoid this problem.

Request API:-
[https://pkc-00000.region.provider.confluent.cloud/kafka/v3/clusters/{cluster_id}/topics/{topic_name}/records](https://pkc-00000.region.provider.confluent.cloud/kafka/v3/clusters/%7Bcluster_id%7D/topics/%7Btopic_name%7D/records)

Sample Payload:

```
{
  "partition_id": 1,
  "headers": [
    {
      "name": "Header-1",
      "value": "SGVhZGVyLTE="
    },
    {
      "name": "Header-2",
      "value": "SGVhZGVyLTI="
    }
  ],
  "key": {
    "type": "BINARY",
    "data": "Zm9vYmFy"
  },
  "value": {
    "type": "JSON",
    "data": {
      "foo": "bar"
    }
  },
  **"timestamp": "2021-02-05T19:14:42Z"**
}
```